# Compilations involving `std::string` cause Windows error status

Tags: c++, string, windows, getlasterror

Minimal example:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[]) {
    HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); //Behavior the same, with or without.
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    std::string str;
    return (int)err; //returns 127 iff line above uncommented, 0 iff commented
}
```

This program returns `127`, which corresponds to `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND` ("The specified procedure could not be found.").  Notice that `err` is set *before* the `std::string` is created.  The program is compiled in debug mode with MSVC 2017.

**Is this behavior expected?  If not, can I get some confirmations (then, I'll file a bug report)?**

Comment: i assume its the last error encountered in your process during process startup.

Comment: If something actually went wrong with the string's construction, you'd be much more likely to run into an exception or a dynamic linker failure.

Comment: If you comment out `std::string str;` do you get the same value?  Also do you get the same value on every run?

Comment: do you actually have a real problem? calling getlasterror before calling any win32  API is obviously meaningless

Comment: @NathanOliver I always get `127`. If I comment the string line, I always get `0`. Also, for reference, this is MSVC 2017.

Comment: Yeahbut that GetStdHandle call will succeed and there is no guarantee that a Win32 API call that succeeds will set the last error to zero or change it in any way.

Comment: Last Error is only set when an API call fails. So same basic question 'do you have a real problem?' Seems you are just curious. I suppose including string support make the run time go through a different initialization path , and that calls an API that fails for some reason. Dont fret about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) returns the last error code to be set by a WinAPI function called by this thread. Note that WinAPI functions do [not necessarily](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680627(v=vs.85).aspx) set a code when they succeed:

> Most functions call SetLastError or SetLastErrorEx only when they fail.

You haven't called a WinAPI function that failed. As such, the error code is indeterminate. It's either uninitialized (meaning undefined behavior) or set by an unknown function (only slightly less meaningless). The standard library uses exceptions to signal errors, not the Windows API.

---

*"Is this behavior expected?"*

The behavior is expected in the sense that *any* value would be acceptable since the function is not being used in the proper context.

Comment: This makes sense. However, I have added a WinAPI function before the call to `GetLastError()` (see edit), and the problem persists.

Comment: @imallett Try a function that fails. Successful functions don't necessarily set the error code. From [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680627(v=vs.85).aspx) : *"Most functions call SetLastError or SetLastErrorEx only when they fail."* You can also try to call `SetLastError` yourself with whatever value you want.

Comment: Replacing line with `GetStdHandle(0)` causes the return to change to `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` ("The handle is invalid."), as-expected.[ EDIT: okay; your edit makes sense.]